# Must declare the scalar variable @trainid

Tags: vb.net

I have Stored Procerdure name Attendancesheet

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Attendancesheet] (@trainid nvarchar (max))

as 
begin

declare @DyPQ as nvarchar (max)
declare @CN as nvarchar(max)
select @CN =ISNULL(@CN+',','')
+ QUOTENAME(lecturename)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT lecturename FROM ATT where trainid=@trainid) as Lectures
--Print @CN

SET @DyPQ= N'
select * from
(
select (select trinsname from trains where trinsid=e.trinsid) as [TrainerNmae],
        lecturename,
        att_status
 from att e where (trainid=@trainid))as p
  pivot
 (
 max(Att_status) for lecturename in(' + @CN + '))as f'  

 execute (@DyPQ);
 end
```

I want to pass @trainid parameter from vb.net 2010 combobox value
the vb.net code is:

```
 Dim connect As New Connection
            connect.getconnection()

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("AttendanceSheet", connect.conn)

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "AttendanceSheet"
            ' ---------------------- define parameter to stored procedure
            Dim trainid As SqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@trainid", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            trainid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            trainid.Value = Me.cbotrainings.SelectedValue.ToString
                       Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
            connect.conn.Close()
            Me.dg1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Have you tried this 'Dim trainid As SqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@trainid", SqlDbType.NVarChar)' without the '@' in the parameter name?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
Dim trainid As SqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trainid", Me.cbotrainings.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim)
```